# Javascript: Simplifying many Regular Expression .replace() into fewer Regex calls

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following javascript function that uses a lot of regex. Is there a way I can simplify this?

```
function encode(str){
    if(typeof str==='number'){
        return str;
    }
    if(typeof str!=='string'){
        return '';
    }
    var enc=str;
    enc=enc.replace(/_/g,'_u');  //underscore
    enc=enc.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g,'_r'); //return
    enc=enc.replace(/&/g,'_a');  //ampersand
    enc=enc.replace(/\\/g,'_b'); //backslash
    enc=enc.replace(/:/g,'_c');  //colon
    enc=enc.replace(/"/g,'_d');  //double quote
    enc=enc.replace(/=/g,'_e');  //equals
    enc=enc.replace(/€/g,'_4');  //euro
    enc=enc.replace(/\>/g,'_g'); //greater than
    enc=enc.replace(/#/g,'_h');  //hash
    enc=enc.replace(/'/g,'_i');  //inverted comma
    enc=enc.replace(/\</g,'_l'); //less than
    enc=enc.replace(/¬/g,'_n');  //not
    enc=enc.replace(/\|/g,'_1'); //pipe
    enc=enc.replace(/¦/g,'_2');  //broken pipe
    enc=enc.replace(/\+/g,'_p'); //plus
    enc=enc.replace(/£/g,'_3');  //pound
    enc=enc.replace(/\?/g,'_q'); //question mark
    enc=enc.replace(/\//g,'_s'); //slash
    enc=enc.replace(/\~/g,'_t'); //tlide
    enc=enc.replace(/\`/g,'_z'); //back quote
    enc=enc.replace(/\s/g,'_0'); //space
    enc=enc.replace(/[\u0000-\u001f]/g,'');
    return enc;
};
```

Comment: Ultimately What is your condition.You want to replace all the special characters with some ur stuff.Isn't it ?

Comment: Why do you want to change it?

Comment: you should describe what you want the regex to do in english with some examples... then someone will help you.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko I just want to know if this can be simplified? Can all those replace calls be merged into one?

Comment: @d'alar'cop Im just trying to encode any string to this unique format, so `'£10 & #change'` would become `'_310_s_a_s_hchange'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var map = {
    "_": "_u",
    "(\r\n|\r|\n)": "_r",
    "&": "_a",
    /* .. etc .. */
};
var i;
var enc = "_abc&";
for (i in map) {
    enc = enc.replace(new RegExp(i, "g"), map[i]);
}
console.log(enc); // _uabc_a
```

I used `new RegExp` because you can't compose a regular expression. Keep in mind that you don't need the delimiters (`/`) and the modifier (`g`) is elsewhere.

Comment: isnt this the same number of regex calls, just in a for loop?

Comment: It is. I see no other way to optimize so I figured you meant this.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was looking to see if I could optimize this, but if I cant then that answers my question.

Comment: @Jimmery see the edit to my answer. That approach is actually twice as fast.

Comment: @m.buettner I just ran the tests in jsPerf and apparently separate replacements are faster? Im running Firefox 24.0

Comment: @Jimmery I just re-ran the benchmark in all my browsers (you can see the results at the bottom). FF 24 is not among them unfortunately, but the callback is conclusively faster (in some browsers even more than twice as fast). So if you're not optimising towards FF 24, the callback should be faster in general. Also, if you want to answer to this comment, please do so on my answer. These comments don't belong to this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating a map of "pattern" to "replacement", you could instead create a map from "string to replace" to "replacement", then use a single replacement function with a callback:

```
var map = {
    "_": "_u",
    "\r\n": "_r",
    "\r": "_r",
    "\n": "_r",
    "&": "_a",
    /* .. etc .. */
};

enc = enc.replace(
        /\r\n|[_\r\n&\\:"=€>#'<¬|¦+£?\/~`\s\u0000-\u001f]/g,
        function(m) {
            return map[m[0]];
        }
);
```

This approach will fail as soon as you add replacement patterns that do not result in a fixed string (because they use a quantifier like `+` or `*`).

However, it is actually significantly faster in most browsers. See [this JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/callback-map-vs-list-of-replacements).

Other than that there is no way to do a conditional replacement (which is what you would need for further optimisation).

Comment: +1 I'm curious if this solution would be slowed down if the `map{}` object is placed directly in the callback function (as an anonymous object literal)? e.g. `s.replace(/[<>&]/g, function(m){return {"<": "&lt;", ">": "&gt;", "&": "&amp;"}[m];})`

Comment: @ridgerunner in production code I'd actually pull the `map` even further out and make it "global", so that it doesn't have to be created everytime someone calls `encode`.